# Function with a pointer to an array argument in C

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-array

I have written code below that contains a function with a pointer to a double array of size 3.My problems is this:
when I pass the address of pointer to a double variable *(that clearly isn't an array)* and then want to change the value of this double variable in function "f" as written below, when I implement in this manner, the result is correct and the value of the variable is changed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(double (*)[3]);
double a = 7.5;

int main()
{
   double* b = &a;
   f(&b);
   printf("a = %lf\n", a);
   return 0;

}
void f(double (*hi)[3])
{
   double **sth = (double **) hi;\
   *(*sth) = 1;

}
```

But when I implement as below the value isn't changed:

```
void f(double (*hi)[3]){
    (*hi)[0] = 1;
}
```

Any idea and suggestion is surely appreciated.

Comment: If you use pointers to arrays, you are almost certainly doing it wrong. In C, you pass a pointer to the first element of an array to functions, not a pointer to an array.

Comment: Also, converting a pointer to an array to a pointer to pointer and then dereferencing the result is undefined behaviour. Don't do that.

Comment: A pointer to array and a pointer to pointer are not the same thing. In addition you switch off compiler warnings by casting a spell. Don't do that, good C code works without casts. The suggestion would be, don't use casts, sort out your types.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to work on your understanding on arrays and pointers -- therefore please update your question.

To get your code to consider this: (1) change *f(&b);* to *f(b);* .. (as you want to pass the pointer, not the address of the pointer) (2) change *double (*hi)[3]* to *double (*hi)*.

Answer (score 1):

First fix the compilation errors your program is giving. After fixing those you will know the problem.

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:8:6: error: passing argument 1 of 'f' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
    f(&b);
      ^
prog.c:2:6: note: expected 'double (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'double **'
 void f(double (*)[3]);
```

http://ideone.com/mueyCU

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(double (*)[3]);
double a = 7.5;

int main()
{
    double* b = &a;
    f(b);
    printf("a = %lf\n", a);
    return 0;

}

void f(double (*hi)[3]){
    (*hi)[0] = 1;
}
```

Above code is not the right way to do things and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: actually I want to understand the syntax I have written above! I know it is complicated and there are much better ways than my code but I do not want the result with another code!!!

Comment: @Mehdi: do you know what is this double (*hi)[3]?

Comment: I think this is a pointer to an array of double type @noman pouigt

Comment: @Mehdi: I have edited the answer.Have a look and regarding your answer it is not right. double (*hi)[3] is a pointer to an array[3] of type double.

Comment: yes it works! but logicly we should send &b to function f, isn't it? @noman pouigt

Comment: @Mehdi: no as b is a pointer. In order to change the content of the pointer you just pass the pointer until and unless you want to change the pointer address in which case you pass the double pointer.

Comment: Look at it from this point of view: function `f` needs as a parameter the address of a part of memory that contains three doubles, one after the other. `a` is only one double. `b` is a pointer that contains the address of `a`, so it's an address of a part of memory that contains one double. When you pass `b` to `f` you are "cheating", because you are passing it an address with less things than the function wants. If `f` only looks at the first double, then nothing seems wrong. But if it accesses `(*hi)[1]` it would look in dark places that nobody should look at.